# Unable to parse unicode characters as a string anymore

Tags: apex, api, json, string, deserialize

A few week ago, my api code that parsed a String just fine, all of the sudden doesn't work when the passed in string is unicode characters.. Here is my code:

```
class Degree {
    String title;
}

class RequestBody {
    List<Degree> degrees;
}

/**
 * POST
 */
@HttpPost
global static void uploadDegrees() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    try {
        // Parse the Request Body
        RequestBody reqBody = (RequestBody)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(), RequestBody.class);

    List<Degree__c> newDegrees = new List<Degree__c>()
    for (Degree deg : reqBody.degrees) {
        Degree__c newDegree = Degree__c();
        newDegree.title__c = deg.title;
        newDegrees.add(newDegree);
    }
    insert newDegrees;
}
```

Then, I have a trigger that gets the value of `title__c` on the new degrees, truncates a copy of title__c down to 80, and sets it as the Name of the record.

However, at the time of the trigger `title__c` is considered `null`.

This happens when the value of `title` in the request is `"title":"\u0646\u0638\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0644\u0648\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0627\u0633\u0648\u0628\u064a\u0629"`

This was all working fine a few weeks ago and wasn't referenced as null, but now it is... Why is APEX referencing that string of unicode characters as null?

Comment: If I simply put this text in a string variable, it works fine. I don't see this to be assigned as `null`. You must be having something else which is causing the problem.

Comment: Everything looks good. I tested this string with some parsing, it came through just fine.

Comment: Yeah, this works fine when I test it in the Open Execution Window, but not when I'm trying to run it live.. #apexsucks